# How can I create an array of the grayscale color pixel values of a 28x28 matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, deep-learning, pixel

I am trying to code a neural network. I am in the very early stages and can't quite get past this problem. I have working code to extract an image from an MNIST database and form it into a matplotlib. In order to continue, I need to extract the grayscale value (between 0 and 255) of each individual pixel. I know it is possible, but I do not know how to access and iterate through each pixel on the figure. Here is an example:
[matplot of handrawn figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pafX.png)

Here is my code thus far:

```
import numpy as np
import gzip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from PIL import Image
f = gzip.open('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','r')

image_size = 28
num_images = 10000


f.read(16)
buf = f.read(image_size * image_size * num_images)
data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float32)
data = data.reshape(num_images, image_size, image_size, 1)
x = random.randrange(0, 10000)
image = np.asarray(data[x]).squeeze()
plt.style.use('grayscale')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

If you can help, thank you so much!

I tried to find out if there was a way to just call pixel values via (row, column) sort of thing, but I couldn't find anything. People have said that its impossible to do on matplot, but if you hover on a pixel you can clearly see the value, so there must be a way to access it. I want to be able to just iterate through the image pixels, but there is no keyword like that.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.  `data[i,j]` will give you the i-th row and j-th column of the data.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html

Comment: @Jody Klymak I am trying to find, in the matplot figure, for every pixel in the matplot figure array, the grayscale value between 0 and 255 and save to values to an array to i can modify them via a sigmoid function.

Comment: why are you doing this "in the matplot figure" rather than on your data?

Answer (score 1):

You have the gray-scale values already. They're in the raw data that you are loading. In the above code, the matrix of values appears to be stored in `image`.

Try adding this directly after you declare `image`.

```py
for i in range(28):
    for j in range(28):
        val = img[i, j]
        if val > 0:
            print(i, j, f' {val}')
```

This will print all pixel values in the matrix-image that are above zero. Looking at the index numbers will show you that the non-0 values are all clustered together in the matrix, giving you an idea that there is an image there.